# How do I get the userdata string from the authentification ticket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

I have added a string as user identity but can't find out how to retrieve it from a class.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
string cookiestr;
HttpCookie ck;

tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUser.Text, DateTime.Now,              
//Amount of minutes for standard session
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, UserCompany);
cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
```

Comment: You noted the line: cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt)? It's not supposed to get the data off. If you can, a crook can too.

Comment: I did it before using this but I have lost the code. Before I managed to add a list of accessible menu items as a list string to the userdata and got them on the pages but now I want to use it for company ID I can't get the data back.

Comment: A ticket is NOT viewdata and should NOT be used like that. Period. It's used to secure your site.

Comment: So what's the userdata property for?

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end...

```
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);


        CompanyID = ticket.UserData;
```